# Porcentagem PHP e Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um tabela MySQL onde é armazenado tipo de produtos. Gostaria de ver a porcentagem de cada produto cadastrado na tabela. Fiz dessa forma:

```
// Verifico o total de produtos cadastrados
$sqlTotal = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM produtos");
$totalProdutos = mysqli_num_rows($sqlTotal);

// Verifico o total do tipo de produtos
$sqlTipo = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE TipoProduto = 'Arroz'");
$totalTipo = mysqli_num_rows($sqlTipo);

// Faço o cálculo
$porcentagem = ($totalProdutos * 100) / $totalTipo;
```

A forma correta é:

```
$porcentagem = ($totalTipo * 100) / $totalProdutos;
```

Estou um pouco inseguro sobre esse código.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A formula está correta sim. Eu particularmente gosto da multiplicação após a divisão:

`( totalCategoria / totalProdutos ) * 100`

É possível fazer o que você quer com apenas uma consulta resumida ao banco:

```
SELECT tipoProduto, count(tipoProduto), 
( count(tipoProduto) / (SELECT count(tipoProduto) FROM produtos) ) * 100 as percentual
FROM produtos
GROUP BY tipoProduto;
```

Assim você tem o percentual de todas as categorias de uma só vez.

Segue exemplo no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3460/4).

Caso precise pode detalhar mais a sua query:

```
SELECT tipoProduto, count(tipoProduto) as totalCategoria,
(SELECT count(tipoProduto) FROM produtos) as totalProdutos, 
( count(tipoProduto) / (SELECT count(tipoProduto) FROM produtos) ) * 100 as percentual
FROM produtos
GROUP BY tipoProduto;
```

Answer (score 0):

É melhor fazer um `Count(id_produto) as Total` na sua QUERY.

```
$sqlTipo = mysqli_query($conexao,"SELECT count(id_produto) as Total FROM produtos WHERE TipoProduto = 'Arroz'");
$totalTipo = mysqli_result($sqlTipo, 0, 'Total');
```

Comment: Certo Diego. Na verdade precisava da regra de três. Encontrei. Para calcular basta fazer dessa forma que editei.